# WinForm lock other application inside form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, embedding

Sorry if this was asked before or if this is stupid.
I am making an application for security staff (night guards) to make his nights more interesting,
Ill love to try embed TV Player inside WinForm. Problem is that TV tuner which  I have has their own application and I can only reproduce TV Signal using that application.  I think If I embed that application inside my application (WinForm) then users is going also to pay more attention at other controls on my application which spouse they watch. I want to make something like it does embed IE in applications, Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explicitly forbidden by the SDK docs, but some appcompat hacks for Windows 3.x apps can make it possible.  Ab/used by several 32-bit programs as well, Acrobat Reader for one.

P/Invoke SetParent(), you'll need the window handle of the app's main window.  Process.MainWindowHandle() with some luck.  MoveWindow to put it in the right place.  Use pinvoke.net for the declarations you'll need.  The fact that this app displays video doesn't improve the odds that this will work out.