# Display an access database inside a form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I want to display an access database inside a form. Is this possible?

I tried searching for this however all of the links explained how to view data from an access database in a form which isn't what I'm after (I want to show the complete access application including the ribbon).

At this stage I only need a yes/no answer unless someone is willing to provide a link/explanation on how to do this.

I use vb.net / C# and visual studio 2013

Comment: Check this i think it is same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950515/winform-lock-other-application-inside-form

Comment: i think you can link youraccess database to server explorer and then access data from there each time to your form.

Comment: @adopilot: thanks for the link... that tells me what I need to know.